# How to show due date column in the trac reports?

Tags: sql, trac

I have [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) installed for managing my online projects. I have also installed a date plugin [DateFieldPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/DateFieldPlugin) in it. I am unable to show this date filed in the custom reports.

The following code generates the normal report.

```
SELECT p.value AS __color__,
owner AS __group__,
id AS ticket, severity, summary, component, milestone, t.type AS type, time AS created,
changetime AS _changetime, description AS _description,reporter AS _reporter
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN enum p ON p.name = t.priority AND p.type = 'priority'
WHERE status = 'assigned'
ORDER BY owner, p.value, t.type, time
```

and I want something like this:

```
SELECT p.value AS __color__,
owner AS __group__,
id AS ticket, severity, summary, component, milestone, t.type AS type, time AS created,
changetime AS _changetime, description AS _description,
reporter AS _reporter, c.value AS Duedate
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN enum p ON p.name = t.priority AND p.type = 'priority', ticket_custom c
WHERE status = 'assigned'
ORDER BY owner, p.value, t.type, time
```

The above code is showing me the due date column though it is showing one task row as multiple times.

Can anybody help me in this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Derek is quit there. Nevertheless, here is the working one:

```
SELECT p.value AS __color__,
owner AS __group__,
id AS ticket, severity, summary, component, milestone, t.type AS type, time AS created,
changetime AS _changetime, description AS _description,
reporter AS _reporter, c.value AS Duedate
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN enum p ON p.name = t.priority AND p.type = 'priority'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ticket_custom c ON t.id = c.ticket AND c.name = 'due_date'
WHERE status = 'assigned'
ORDER BY owner, p.value, t.type, time
```

Only you will have to replace the *c.name* value to match with *your date fields name*, if it's not 'due_date' like in my configuration.

Background: The 'ticket_custom' table definition is just one key-value-pair per row, as the call for the schema reveals:

```
sqlite> .schema ticket_custom
CREATE TABLE ticket_custom (
    ticket integer,
    name text,
    value text,
    UNIQUE (ticket,name)
);
```

Please note the *primary key* is not just the ticket number, but ticket (number) and (custom column) name combined. Hence an additional WHERE clause is required on the JOIN or you'll still get multiple rows - one for each custom field of all matching tickets. This is in contrast to the main table 'ticket', where all information for one ticket is in a single row.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The exact code didn't work, though I just removed the AND clause (AND c.name = 'due_date') from the query and it seems work. Let me try it out in a bit different format.
The table is already there for due date as ticket_custom, it was created by the plugin I installed for new custom filed (date).

Comment: Well, if the custom field name is 'date' then 'AND c.name='date' is what you'll need. As outlined above you can't just join table ticket_custom, at least with >1 custom fields per ticket. You'll need to select by name, what values should be JOINed as additional column to the ticket table - uh, just noticed my error ... corrected the query by moving the name selector where it belongs: in the JOIN part. Try again please.

Comment: The duedate column is coming blank?

Comment: With this query, 

**SELECT p.value AS __color__,
owner AS __group__,
id AS ticket, severity, summary, component, milestone, t.type AS type, time AS created,
changetime AS _changetime, description AS _description,
reporter AS _reporter, date(c.value) AS duedate
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN enum p ON p.name = t.priority AND p.type = 'priority'
LEFT JOIN ticket_custom c ON t.id = c.ticket
WHERE status = 'assigned'
ORDER BY owner, p.value, t.type, time**

I am able to print the due date but its format is not as current date. How can I make current date and due date format same?

Comment: Can't do much to date/time format of your custom field, since it's a formatted string. This is a DateFieldPlugin limitation. I'm working with a patched Trac here, and save date/time like Trac (time, changetime): in POSIX microseconds. Then you could use the special column names as explained in http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracReports#Automaticallyformattedcolumns (or same page in your own Trac wiki docs). Better store true timestamps for searching as well - as soon as it is available in the official branch.

Comment: And there is another caveat to note from studying Trac wiki docs: Use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN, "If you have tickets in the database before you declare the extra fields". - from http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracReports#Reportingoncustomfields | I changed my code above accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't specifying a join condition on `ticket_custom`. Therefore, it's doing a `CROSS JOIN`, which joins every record from `ticket_custom` to every record in the rest of your query. So if your `ticket left join enum` originally returned 100 rows, and `ticket_custom` has 20, you'll have 2000 resulting rows in your 2nd query.

You need to determine how ticket_custom relates to the other tables and provide an appropriate predicate. Most likely, it's something like this:

```
SELECT p.value AS __color__,
owner AS __group__,
id AS ticket, severity, summary, component, milestone, t.type AS type, time AS created,
changetime AS _changetime, description AS _description,
reporter AS _reporter, c.value AS Duedate
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN enum p ON p.name = t.priority AND p.type = 'priority'
LEFT JOIN ticket_custom c ON t.id = c.ticket_id
WHERE status = 'assigned'
ORDER BY owner, p.value, t.type, time
```

(See new LEFT JOIN line). The columns are a guess - you'll need to substitute whichever columns correctly relate the 2 tables.

Comment: Thanks... It somehow helped me to understand the logic clearly.